# We still can’t sleep. / We can’t sleep yet

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering if these two sentences mean the same thing to you, or are they different?

- We still can’t sleep.
- We can’t sleep yet.

Thank you.

Comment: The first I take to mean that they had been trying to get to sleep but are now reporting failure. The second might mean that they are awake for some purpose of expectation of a coming event. They will not rest until it has happened or has been resolved.

Comment: Thank you, Elliot!

Comment: The first might also mean that, in general, not just on one occasion, they are unable to sleep. For example, they're staying in a noisy hotel for a week. Someone asks them on their fourth morning there,"How has your stay been?" They might answer, "It's very noisy here at night, and we still can't sleep." Here, they would mean that they haven't slept well for three nights.

Answer (score 2):

- We still can't sleep

  - This implies continuation of the past.
- We can't sleep yet

  - This implies constraint because of the future.